# split vector or data.frame into intervals by condition and print interval's first and last value

Tags: r, intervals, data-munging

I have data.frame which looks like this:

```
v1 <- c(1:10)
v2 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
dfb <- data.frame(v1, v2)

> dfb
   v1    v2
1   1 FALSE
2   2 FALSE
3   3  TRUE
4   4 FALSE
5   5 FALSE
6   6 FALSE
7   7  TRUE
8   8 FALSE
9   9 FALSE
10 10 FALSE
```

I need those operations:

1. split data.frame into intervals according to `V2` if is `TRUE`
2. rows where `V2` is `TRUE` will be last interval element
3. if the last element is not `TRUE` it will be treated as if is (this can be easily achieved by adding `TRUE` to last vector position)
4. print `V1` as first and last element from created intervals

after this operations my results should look like this:

```
  > df_final
   Vx Vy
    1 3
    4 7
    8 10
```

I've tried `cumsum` on `v2` vector but `TRUE` values are treated as first interval element not last

```
> split(v2, cumsum(v2==TRUE))
$`0`
[1] FALSE FALSE

$`1`
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`2`
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `c(0, head(cumsum(v2), -1)))` as grouping variable? Like `with(dfb, aggregate(v1, list(grp = c(0, head(cumsum(v2), -1))), range))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `cumsum`, you just have to slightly adjust `v2`:

```
v3 <- c(TRUE,v2[-length(v2)])
v3
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

res <- split(v2,cumsum(v3))
res[[length(res)]][length(last(res))] <- T
res
$`1`
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

$`2`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

$`3`
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

df_final <- data.frame(Vx=which(v3),Vy=which(unlist(res,use.names=F)))
df_final
  Vx Vy
1  1  3
2  4  7
3  8 10
```

Comment: need to say that `last` function is from `data.table` package

Answer (score 1):

Get df_final

```
Vy <- c(which(dfb$v2 %in% T),nrow(dfb))
Vx <- c(1,Vy[-length(Vy)]+1)

df_final <- data.frame(Vx,Vy)
```

Split Df

```
library(data.table)

split_ind <- rleid(dfb$v2)-!(rleid(dfb$v2) %% 2)

split(dfb,split_ind)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, can you please briefly explain how does last two commands work?

Comment: Also I guess that if `V1` were some random values then additional indexing would be necessary e.g. `A <- dfb[Vx, ]$v1; B <- dfb[Vy, ]$v1`

Comment: "Vector %% 2" gives 1 for odd number and 0 for even. The "! " negates the preceding. I saw that the TRUE were in a Group that is even. So I want to make them one smaller so they end up in the preceding group. hope this helps. Hava a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I will also post my answer heavily inspired by Eldioo, this one is useful also when `V1` are non numeric values and avoids using `split` and `cumsum` functions.

Input:

```
v1 <- letters[1:10]
v2 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
dfb <- data.frame(v1, v2)

> dfb
   v1    v2
1   a FALSE
2   b FALSE
3   c  TRUE
4   d FALSE
5   e FALSE
6   f FALSE
7   g  TRUE
8   h FALSE
9   i FALSE
10  j FALSE
```

Solution:

```
# data wrangling
library(data.table)
dfb["v3"] <- c(TRUE,dfb$v2[-length(dfb$v2)])
dfb["v4"] <- dfb$v2
dfb$v4[length(dfb$v4)] <- T
Vx <- which(dfb$v3)
Vy <- which(dfb$v4)
Vx <- dfb[Vx, ]$v1
Vy <- dfb[Vy, ]$v1

# for debugging purposes
dfb
   v1    v2    v3    v4
1   a FALSE  TRUE FALSE
2   b FALSE FALSE FALSE
3   c  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
4   d FALSE  TRUE FALSE
5   e FALSE FALSE FALSE
6   f FALSE FALSE FALSE
7   g  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
8   h FALSE  TRUE FALSE
9   i FALSE FALSE FALSE
10  j FALSE FALSE  TRUE

# final results
data.frame(Vx, Vy)
  Vx Vy
1  a  c
2  d  g
3  h  j
```